# How can I programatically recreate these WebSphere logs due to unsynchronized access to HashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety

We have few components in our project extending `HashMap`.
Due to unsynchronized access to the `HashMap` object we are getting the logs like the below one in production:

```
ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W:Thread "webcontainer:5" has been active for 864096 milliseconds and may be hung.There is/are 5 thread(s) in the total server that may be hung.
    at java.util.HashMap.findNonNullKeyEntry(HashMap.java:525)
    at java.util.HashMap.putImpl(HashMap.java:622)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:605
```

I want to recreate this for the testing purpose and tried spawning different threads putting and getting the `HashMap` object, but still no breakthroughs. Also, I have set `loadFactor` to 0.1 so that resizing of the `HashMap` will occur more frequently, which we are analysing is causing the issue (structural changes in the `HahMap`).

We are using IBM Java version 6.

How can I recreate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refer to the code by gwoolsey at [JDK-6611637](https://web.archive.org/web/20101204055312/http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6611637).  I was able to reproduce the problem with this.